# Reference to an enclosing class method cannot be extracted on refactoring

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

When I want to do "Extract to widget", it raises an error : "reference to an enclosing class method cannot be extracted"

I know there is some variables that must get their data from class constructor but I want Android studio to extract the widget then, I will correct the mistaken codes, like Visual Studio that without any error extract the code to a new widget then it needs to copy the new extracted widget to a new dart file and correct the mistakes.

I want to extract the Card widget part.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as prefix0;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../model/transaction.dart';

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions;
  final Function deleteTx;

  TransactionList(this.transactions, this.deleteTx);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return transactions.isEmpty
        ? LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (ctx, constraint) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'There is no transaction',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    textDirection: prefix0.TextDirection.rtl,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                      height: constraint.maxHeight * 0.6,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/yalda.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ))
                ],
              );
            },
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: transactions.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return **Card**(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 5),
                elevation: 5,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: FittedBox(
                          child: Text('\$${transactions[index].amount}')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    transactions[index].title,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(DateFormat.yMMMd()
                      .format(transactions[index].date)
                      .toString()),
                  trailing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 360
                      ? FlatButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () => deleteTx(transactions[index].id),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                          label: const Text('Delete'),
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                  )
                      : IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                          color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                          onPressed: () => deleteTx(transactions[index].id),
                        ),
                ),
              );
            });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Simply use "Extract Method" instead of "Extract Widget". VSCode will add all the returns and references.

Edit: If you want to use "Extract Widget" only then simply wrap that widget in a Container and then use "Extract Widget" on that widget.
If that doesn't work, comment out setState() function inside the widget and try again.

Comment: we can use Extract method or we manually extract the widget, but is there any convention when to use extract method or extract widget? sorry I am new in Flutter :)

Answer (score 8):

Your deleteTx might contain a setState(() {}) method, try to comment that part of your code where you're calling deleteTx  it and just put it back after your extraction.

Comment: You get the same error even without any setstate in there.

Answer (score 4):

transform onpressed etc. property to comments and then try again 'Extract Widget' and go on

Answer (score 4):

Just `remove` or `comment` the `setState() {}` from your `widget` and it gonna works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case it was because of **ListView.builder** as yours.

So it is easy to fix, Simply make a class and *return Card* in *Widget build* and return it in **ListView.builder** inside the *TransactionList class* with the desired arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If you can comment out `deleteTx(transactions[index].id)` parts of your code and then use `onPressed: (){}`, you will be able to extract to widget.

After the extraction you can use:

```dart
onPressed: (){
    setState(() {
        deleteTx(transactions[index].id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to care about a few things:

1. Whenever you are extracting a widget, that widget should not contain any variable which is used in the current working page.
2. All the functions or methods should be parametric.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are referencing a variable(for example, `transactions`) in your `Card` widget from the enclosing class i.e. `TransactionList`. The best way to extract in this case could be to just make stateless/stateful widget outside your class and cut the `Card` widget and paste it as the return type of the build method of that Widget you created. And you can reference those variables using the constructor of that widget you created.

Answer (score 0):

there might be some local referance to the variable in the current class,so if there some referance we cant extract a widget from there.

Answer (score 0):

If we extract the widget it will StatelessWidget. StatelessWidget doesn't support changing state so if you use any Onchange property SetState it never extract
so please remove `setState(() {});`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for this warning.

1. If you are using setState inside the block which you are
   trying to extract. The solution for this is to try commenting
   on the setState block.
2. If you are using any properties or functions related to the
   existing class then also we can see this warning. Solution for this is to either try by making the properties or function globally accessible (if possible) or try to pass the only the value to the widget as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have a Stateless widget, so setState is not necessary.

Also widgets are more performatic than methods, according to this Flutter video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo.

So we should just remove anything related to State from your widgets to be able to extract it.

I was able to extract by:

1. Create an AppState Class that extends ChangeNotifier to deal with TransactionList
2. Removing the DateFormat part changing just to a string. (This was just o mock your object)
3. Changed the FlatButton to IconButton once it was not recognized here.

And finally I was able to extract it, here is the code before the extraction:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as prefix0;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../model/transaction.dart';

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Transaction> transactions;
  final Function deleteTx;

  TransactionList(this.transactions, this.deleteTx);

}

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var transactions = appState.transactions;
    return transactions.isEmpty? LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (ctx, constraint) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'There is no transaction',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              textDirection: prefix0.TextDirection.rtl,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
                height: constraint.maxHeight * 0.6,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/yalda.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ))
          ],
        );
      },
    )
  : ListView.builder(
      itemCount: transactions.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        return Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 5),
          elevation: 5,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: FittedBox(
                    child: Text('\$${transactions[index].amount}')),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              transactions[index].title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
            ),
            subtitle: Text("blue"),
            trailing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 360
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => appState.deleteTx(transactions[index].id),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
            )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                    color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                    onPressed: () => appState.deleteTx(transactions[index].id),
                  ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

When it comes to organizing your code for readability and reusability, there are two key approaches: the "extract method" and the "extract widget" techniques.

1. Extract Method: This technique involves isolating a block of code into its own function or method. By doing so, you can improve the readability of your code by giving meaningful names to these extracted chunks of functionality. Additionally, if you find that you need the same functionality in multiple places, you can easily reuse the extracted method without duplicating code.
2. Extract Widget: In Flutter or similar frameworks, the "extract widget" approach is analogous to the "extract method" in traditional programming. It involves encapsulating a portion of UI code into its own widget. This not only improves readability by giving a clear name to the encapsulated UI component but also facilitates reusability. If you find that you need the same UI component in multiple parts of your application, you can simply reuse the extracted widget instead of duplicating the UI code.

By employing these techniques judiciously, you can enhance the maintainability and efficiency of your codebase, making it easier to understand, modify, and extend.

**Resolution : Comment setState and extract Widget.**

When faced with the limitation of being unable to directly extract a method due to references to an enclosing class method like `setState` in Flutter, one workaround is to temporarily comment out those lines before extracting the widget. Afterwards, reinstate the commented lines and pass necessary parameters by instantiating the class. This maintains functionality while benefiting from the reusability and readability of extracted widgets

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "Extract Method". It's a simple way. VSCode will add all the returns and references.

Comment: You must be new to flutter. It's advisable to always use widgets rather than methods. That's not a solution at all.

Answer (score -1):

Just **remove** or **comment** the `setState() {}` from your widget

Or

Just **remove** or **comment** the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` from your widget